# argument resolve() must be array null given symfony option resolver

Tags: symfony

How exactly to solve this error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver::resolve() must be of the type array, null given
```

Code:

```
private function getProductOptions(Request $request)
{
    $resolver = new OptionsResolver();
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'product' => null,
    ]);

    $resolver->setAllowedValues('product', null);
    return $resolver->resolve(json_decode($request->getContent()));
}
//...
$option = $this->getOption($request);
$user->setProduct($option['product']);
```

The error occures when I'm not sending a product(string) option in request. Any ideas?

Comment: `json_decode($request->getContent())` may return `null`, account for it

Comment: Hm..yes, I already thought about it and that is my only problem.. how to avoid it?

Comment: You can't as it comes from the request and it can be literally anything

Comment: Don't know exactly what you mean..

Comment: lets start by explaining the error message 
(Argument 1) was given to (OptionsResolver::resolve())

which was meant to be an array but it is null .
furthermore 
Argument 1 = $request->getContent()

Comment: now you need to check the source of your request

Comment: and make sure it never returns null what you can do is create an empty array instead of allowing it to return null